# Java Client - Accessing Kubernetes cluster and MQ cluster over SSL

Tags: java, kubernetes, ssl-certificate, ibm-mq

Hava a Java client application that can connect to a Kubernetes cluster over SSL using `io.kubernetes.client.ApiClient` okay on its own. The same Java client application can also connect to an MQ cluster over SSL on its own. The same application however cannot connect to both Kubernetes cluster over SSL and MQ cluster over SSL all at once.

I believe this may be due to the fact that only one SSL key/trust store can be configured on a JVM at any one time? But do not know what the best way forward is in order to resolve this.

What would be the simplest way to allow a Java client to connect to both a Kubernetes cluster and an MQ cluster each over SSL?

The two configurations shown in this post result in the following error being thrown when both are run together:

```
WARN  io.kubernetes.client.util.credentials.ClientCertificateAuthentication - Could not create key manager for Client Certificate authentication.
java.security.UnrecoverableKeyException: Cannot recover key
```

The Kubernetes part of the client application connects to the Kubernetes cluster by configuring as follows:

```
String kubeConfigPath = "~/.kube/config";
apiClient = ClientBuilder.kubeconfig(
                    KubeConfig.loadKubeConfig(new FileReader(kubeConfigPath))).build();
apiClient.getHttpClient().setReadTimeout(0, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
            Configuration.setDefaultApiClient(apiClient);
```

The Mq part of the client application connects to the MQ cluster by configuring as follows:

```
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStore", "C:\\tmp\\ssl\\dev\\mgr_mq.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.trustStorePassword", "password");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStore", "C:\\tmp\\ssl\\dev\\mgr_mq.jks");
System.setProperty("javax.net.ssl.keyStorePassword", "password");
System.setProperty("com.ibm.mq.cfg.useIBMCipherMappings", "false");

java.net.URL ccdt = new URL("file:./config/qmgrs/mgr/AMQCLCHL.TAB");
MQQueueManager mqQueueManager = new MQQueueManager("*mgr", ccdt);
```

Comment: What keystore does it use with kubernetes alone?

Comment: For kubernetes alone the configuration is a YAML config file which refers to a client-certificate .crt file and a client-key .key file.

Comment: Can you place the client cert in the `mgr_mq.jks` file and see if it will be picked up by kubernetes?  Also you do not need to specify truststore if it points to the same file as keystore.

Comment: I can certainly try this. Do you know if the client cert needs to be added in with a specific label or alias? Or will any string do?

Comment: I think any string will do.  Java will present the cert that matches the trusted signers presented by the TLS server you are connecting to, it does not base it on the label.

Comment: I've tried but it did not like it. I believe the problem is with Kubernetes client API itself which seems to force a new truststore to be created in which then the kubernetes client config's certificate in `~/.kube/config' is then added to. I don't think there is an option in the API to add the cert to an already existing trustore so I may need to look into updating the API code itself to add cert to an existing trustore instead of a new one. Will need to get familiarised with kubernetes client API code to do this however.

Answer (score 1):

The [Kubernetes java client API code](https://github.com/kubernetes-client/java) seems to force adding the certificate referenced in `.kube/config` to a new truststore that it creates new each time before adding the certificate to it.

This seems to take place in `ClientCertifiacteAuthentication.java` class' `provide(ApiClient client)` method:

```
final KeyManager[] keyManagers = SSLUtils.keyManagers(certificate, key, algo, "", null, null);
```

Where the two `null` values which are `keyStoreFile` and `keyStorePassphrase` then force a new truststore to be created within.

So for now and to prove that a solution is possible I have overriden this class to be:

```
final KeyManager[] keyManagers = SSLUtils.keyManagers(certificate, key, algo, "password", "C:\\tmp\\ssl\\dev\\mgr_mq.jks", "password");
```

With this overriden code, both Kubernetes cluster and MQ cluster can be successfully connected to over SSL within the same JVM.